# clistview a path in itemView in yii

Tags: yii

I have a widget that renders a file. From there, it has a clistview. But the path is not working. I am getting the error `require(): Filename cannot be empty`. 
So originally I had the page render from $model, but I realized I should be using clistview. It works fine if I just do a renderPartial $model but it doesn't work in clistview.

from my widget:

```
$this->renderFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.grid'). '/index.php', 
array('product'=>$product));
```

pass to my grid/index.php. I'm showing both ways I had. The top one works but I would need to do a foreach loop. I want to get rid of that due to pagination problems, so I want to use clistview.

```
<?php 
// this works fine, but not what I want.
// $this->controller->renderPartial('//grid/_view',array(
//      'product'=>$product,
// ))
?>
    <?php 
//    $path = '//grid/_view'; I've tried something like this and put it in itemView. It doesn't work.
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$product,
            'itemView'=>'//grid/_view',
            'template' => '{pager}{items}',
    ); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Check this 'itemView'=>'application.views.grid._view'

Comment: ooh that was easy! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can set path for itemView as alias

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
   'itemView'=>'application.views.grid._view'
```